# What is Sentinel Chain? Is it a cryptocurrency scam?

Tags: blockchain, currencies

What is [Sentinel Chain](https://citicoins.com/sentinel-chain/)? Is it a cryptocurrency scam?
Can somebody help me? Thx!!!

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Update August 2020 - the URL in the question no longer exists. A different URL for sentinel chain has "latest news" etc dating from mid 2019. Whether or not it was a scam, it doesn't seem to have been wildly successful.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like any other of those exchange like sites. That does not necessarily make it a scam.